# How can I prove that $\Bbb{P}(X>0)\geq \frac{\Bbb{E}(X)^2}{\Bbb{E}(X^2)}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, stochastic-calculus, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I have the following problem:

> Let $X$ be a nonnegative random variable such that $\Bbb{E}(X^2)<\infty$ Then show that $$\Bbb{P}(X>0)\geq \frac{\Bbb{E}(X)^2}{\Bbb{E}(X^2)}$$

I would like to get some hints, because I did the following:

Let me define $U:=X$ and $V:=\Bbb{1}_{\{X>0\}}$. Then clearly $U\in L^2$. But also $V\in L^2$ since $$\int_\Omega (\Bbb{1}_{\{X>0\}})^2 \Bbb{P}(d\omega)=\int_\Omega \Bbb{1}_{\{X>0\}}\Bbb{P}(d\omega)=\Bbb{P}(X>0)\leq 1$$In addition we have that $\Bbb{E}(V^2)=\Bbb{E}((\Bbb{1}_{\{X>0\}})^2)=\Bbb{E}(\Bbb{1}_{\{X>0\}})=\Bbb{P}(X>0)$. Now applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we get $\Bbb{E}(|UV|)^2\leq \Bbb{E}(U^2)\cdot\Bbb{E}(V^2)=\Bbb{E}(U^2)\cdot\Bbb{P}(X>0)$ so $$\Bbb{P}(X>0)\geq \frac{\Bbb{E}(|\Bbb{1}_{\{X>0\}}X|)^2}{\Bbb{E}(X^2)}$$

Now I see that $\Bbb{E}(|\Bbb{1}_{\{X>0\}}X|)=\Bbb{E}(\Bbb{1}_{\{X>0\}}X)=\Bbb{E}(X)$ since the lebesgue mesure doesn't see the nullsets.

Is this correct like this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, unless the problem clarified that $P(X=0)=0$ but if that was the case you could just take $V=1$

Comment: But what is then the point of writing $P(X>0)$ if it is just 1. Nonnegative means $X\geq 0$

Comment: @AntonV. but I still do not see where this problem should appear in our proof

Comment: The problem doesn't specify that $X$ is continuous, so if it is a coinflip ($X=0$ with probabilty 1/2 and 1 otherwise), then the final step of your proof doesn't work.

Comment: I'm an idiot, it is not because the probabilty of $X=0$ is 0, but just that $X=0$ there that it doesn't contribute to the expected value

Comment: @AntonV. so I think it doesn't contribute because I could split the integral over ${X=0}$ which is zero under the lebesgue measure right?

Comment: I posted an answer, because it was too long for a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything about your proof is correct, except for the final line "since the lebesgue mesure doesn't see the nullsets." This is only true for continuous variables, but your problem doesn't mention that $X$ must be continuous. If $X$ is discrete, so for example if $X$ a coin flip $P(X=0)=P(X=1)=\frac{1}{2}$, it does not hold that $\Bbb{E}[\Bbb{1}_{\{X\neq 1\}}X]=\Bbb{E}[X]$, even though the set $\{1\}$ is a null-set for the Lebesgue measure.

The reason why it is correct that $\Bbb{E}[\Bbb{1}_{\{X>0 \}}X]=\Bbb{E}[X]$ is actually much simpler, and it is that $\Bbb{1}_{\{X>0 \}}X=X$. They are the *same* random variable since if $\Bbb{1}_{\{X>0 \}}=0$, then $X$ is already $0$.

In general, for any random variable $X$ (discrete or continuous) $\Bbb{1}_{\{X\neq 0 \}}X=X$.
This is not true in general: $\Bbb{1}_{\{X\neq a \}}X\neq X$ for $a\neq 0$. See for example the coin flip $\Bbb{1}_{\{X\neq 1\}}X\neq X$.

Comment: Do I see it correct that $\Bbb{E}(\Bbb{1}_{\{X\neq 1\}}X)=X\Bbb{P}(X=0)$?

Comment: Do you mean in case $X$ is the coin flip or in general?

Comment: In the coin flip so your first paragraph where you wrote "If $X$ is discrete so for example $X$ a coin flip ..."

Comment: Ah no then it is zero

Comment: So $\Bbb{E}(\Bbb{1}_{\{X\neq 1\}}X)=0\cdot \Bbb{P}(X=0)=0$ is this right?

Comment: Kind of, the loose $X$ on the right hand side doesn't make sense since you already took expectation, but I see the idea. $\Bbb{E}[\Bbb{1}_{\{X\neq 1\}}X]= 0\cdot P(X=0)+0\cdot P(X=1)=0$.

Comment: My comment was too late :p

Comment: hahah it really seemed strange that I get a random variable if I take the expectation value. But now it makes sense thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

From Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$\Bbb{E}(X)=\Bbb{E}(1_{\{X>0\}}X)\leq \sqrt{\Bbb{E}(1_{\{X>0\}}^2)}\cdot \sqrt{\Bbb{E}(X^2)} = \sqrt{P(X>0)}\cdot \sqrt{\Bbb{E}(X^2)}$. Therefore
$\Bbb{E}(X)^2 \leq P(X>0)\cdot \Bbb{E}(X^2)$

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Just to mention that it would also be true if we only had $\mathbb E[X]\ge0$. Indeed, since $\mathbb E[X]\le\mathbb E[X1_{\{X>0\}}]$, you could just square the inequality and prove the claim.

Comment: Sorry I don't see what you mean by "if we only had..." you mean instead of positivity of $X$?

Comment: Yes sorry for the lack of clarity. If $X\in L^2$ and $\mathbb E[X]\ge0$ then the inequality holds.